# How to order SQL query result on condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements

i have the this SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM merchant ORDER BY category ASC
```

that gives this output:

```
accommodation
education
food
general
health
money
shopping
sport
transport
```

How to put the row that contains "general" at the start (or the end) of the result?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the results you're working with because it's not clear what you're looking for? Where is "General" coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE` expression in `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT category  
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT category 
  FROM merchant ) t
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN category = 'General' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
   category ASC
```

`CASE` guarantees that rows with `General` will be sorted first. The second argument orders the rest of the categories in ascending order.

Comment: It doesn't work... the error should be this: `ERROR: in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list` (i translated it from italian)

Comment: If i remove `DISTINCT` it works... but i get all duplicates

Comment: @smartmouse You have to use a sub-query. Please check the edit I made.

Comment: Excuse me, can you tell me how to apply the same at this query? `SELECT DISTINCT cat.it as category
FROM merchant
JOIN category as cat ON cat.origine = merchant.category
WHERE cat.origine != 'money'
ORDER BY category ASC`. I cannot do it :(

Comment: @smartmouse Something like: `SELECT category
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT cat.it as category 
FROM merchant 
JOIN category as cat 
ON cat.origine = merchant.category 
WHERE cat.origine != 'money' ) t
ORDER BY category ASC`

Comment: It is correct, but adding the case expression it stop to work: `SELECT category FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT cat.it as category FROM merchant JOIN category as cat ON cat.origine = merchant.category WHERE cat.origine != 'money' ) t ORDER BY CASE WHEN category = 'general' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, category ASC`. It doesn't give errors but general isn't at the first position

Comment: @smartmouse That's probably because `category` of the outer `SELECT` is not what `category` in the OP is. What's the difference between `cat.origine` and `cat.it` ?

Comment: category is a table that contains category names in english and .it .en and so on are their translated versions. origine is the original language.

Comment: @smartmouse So you are actually selecting the italian vesion? The use the italian name in place of `'general'` inside `CASE`.

Comment: Sorry... if i would set "general" as the last category instead of the first... how to change the CASE expression?

Comment: @smartmouse Just use `THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT category 
FROM  merchant 
WHERE category = 'general'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT category 
FROM merchant
WHERE category NOT IN ('general')
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It's just separating the `merchant` table in two parts and then reconstructs it ordering by `category`.